# How do I merge the column names?

Tags: merge

I have data in `mydata`
and I have column of `year1,year2,year3,year4`.
How do I merge it so that it turns `year1,year2,year3,year4` as just one column of `Year`?

Answer (score 0):

How do you want you data to show ?
as 4 separate entries in a cell If so you could use something like the below pasted in the total year cell `=A1& " "&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1`

This link may help [Merge Columns](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/510-merge-columns-keep-data.html)

Comment: sorry, I meant in the programming language R. I'd like to show it in one column